# Change NAT IP for Proxmox (Keep host IP)

Tags: networking, linux-networking, proxmox

I have a Proxmox server with many IPv4 addresses available to it. As it stands, an instance (Either LXC or KVM) that connects out to the Internet will be connecting from the host's IP address.

For both management and security purposes, I'd like to be able to give the virtual NAT a "dedicated" IP address, separate from the host's primary address.

Right now, I can add dedicated IP addresses to individual machines (both LXC and KVM) with ease by first requesting a "virtual MAC" from my provider to be assigned to the address, and then configuring the network card with the new MAC and the desired address.

I suppose it's possible to set up one of these machines with OpenVPN and just have every other container connect to it, and then out, but this seems like overengineering when a simpler solution is likely under my nose.